# Can you have an embedded registration with universal MFA set up without needing to login to Auth0?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, auth0

I'm trying to figure out something about setting up multi-factor authentication after registration in Auth0, but I can’t seem to figure it out or find anything about it in the docs.

I have an embedded registration form in Vue.js where the user can sign up for an account after being invited to the platform. I'm trying to use the universal pages of Auth0 as much as possible. I've chosen to use an embedded registration form because the user can only register on invitation, plus there is a lot of extra data that we need from the user (more than the 10 fields which we can use in Auth0).

After the user fills in their details, an account is created via both our API/database and Auth0. After this is done, the user needs to set up 2-FA, preferably in a universal page of Auth0, but with the design of our application (which is already implemented).

We redirect the user to the Auth0 flow, but then the user needs to log in first. The flow feels a bit weird to first register (where you fill in your email and password) and then immediately need to log back in again after clicking the register button to set up MFA. I couldn’t find anything in the documentation about this, but perhaps I totally missed it.

Comment: without any of the MFA, do you still need to login after registering?